# Нажатие кнопки при загрузке документа

Tags: javascript, jquery

День добрый.

Есть код на jQuery. При нажатии на кнопки происходит сортировка div-ов. Хотелось бы чтобы при загрузке страницы одна из кнопок уже была выбрана по умолчанию. Ниже фрагмент кода, но почему-то не срабатывает(((

```
----------
 // bind sort button click
 $('.sort-by-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var sortValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-value');
    $grid.isotope({ sortBy: sortValue });
 });

 //при загрузке 
 $(window).load(function() {
        $('.sort-by-button-group').trigger('click');
  });
```

(использую плагин Isotope, если кому важно)

Еще побывал

```
//при загрузке  
$(document).ready(function() {
    $grid.isotope({ sortBy: name });
});
```

где name - имя нужной кнопки

Comment: Было бы неплохо еще и HTML, чтобы можно было легко воспроизвести.

Comment: По сути конечно, мне вообще нажатие кнопки не нужно, мне нужна сортировка. Пробывал вот такой код, тоже не идет  // bind sort button click
    $('.sort-by-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var sortValue = $(this).attr('data-sort-value');
    $grid.isotope({ sortBy: sortValue });
  });
  //при загрузке 
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $grid.isotope({ sortBy: name });
  });

Comment: Добавляйте код в вопрос. В комментариях черт ногу сломит, если постить туда код

Comment: В последнем примере вопроса `name` - это переменная или вы забыли кавычки и поэтому он не работает?

Comment: переменная, с этим все норм

Comment: Блин))))))))))))) Дураком себя чувствую. Действительно в кавычках дело, всем спасибо!

Comment: Но ответ @IonDen тоже примите во внимание. Все очень правильно написано. Сам хотел ответить, но он меня опередил :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, то что вы просите - это неправильное проектирование.

Чтобы вышло хорошо, вам нужно вынести код сортировки за пределы обработчика кликов и оформить как отдельную функцию. В этой ситуации вы сможете выполнять сортировку не только нажимая кнопки, но и из любого друго места внутри программы.

Это делается примерно так:

```
function sortBy (value) {
    $grid.isotope({ sortBy: value });
}

// далее вы можете вызвать сортировку как по клику:
$('.sort-by-button-group').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    var sortValue = $(this).data('sortValue');
    sortBy(sortValue);
});

// так и с заранее предустановленным value
$(document).ready(function () {
    sortBy('testValue'); // видите, никакие клики не нужны
});
```

P.S. В вашем примере ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь триггернуть клик на группе, в то время, когда обработчик висит на вложенных в группу элементах `button`.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `$(document).ready(function()...)` вместо `load`.

Comment: Не идет, пытался. Хотя кнопки при этом не работают